# Adding value to a cell element specified by array

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am looking for a vectorized solution!

I have two arrays for example:

```
idx=[1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 8 9 9]; %%//Integers,sorted
val=[1 4 8 2 5 3 9 1 4 8 2 5 6 7 1 4 8 3 9]; %%//respective Values (could be anything)
```

Now i want to create a cell array which contains in his elements specified by `idx` the according values of `val`. So the result should be a `[9x1] cell` with:

```
[1 4 8]
[2 5]
[3 9]
[1 4 8]
[2 5]
[6]
[7]
[1 4 8]
[3 9]
```

I know I could loop over the values from 1 to 9 and use horzcat while idx is equal to my loop index but I am looking for a vectorized solution. Reason is, that I am trying to change a loop solution of a problem to vectorized solution yet I am stuck here

Comment: Why do you want it in that form? You might find that whatever you were going to do next might be easier from your `idx` and `val` matrix using functions like `accumarray`

Comment: @Dan I need them because those arrays were just examples. In my code later on I will have different datapoints which I have to sort and "join" following specific arguments (idx). Also I was interested in how to better work with cell-datatypes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `accumarray`:

```
 out = accumarray(idx(:),val(:),[],@(x){x},{});
```

Comment: +1, nearly as fast as my mat2cell solution, but much simpler and more robust (can deal with gaps in idx like `[1,1,3,3]`, can deal with idx not sorted). To match the example data, a transpose is missing: `out = accumarray(idx.',val.',[],@(x){x});`

Comment: @Daniel was just about to write the same. I checked with running the codes 10k times. yours took 1second his 2.5 seconds. Didn't check rather it is more robust but I take it you did. Thx for that and both answers +1

Answer (score 4):

```
mat2cell(val,1,diff([0,find(diff(idx)),numel(idx)]))
```

Maybe someone finds a possibility to get rid of the `find`, then it's probably faster.